# If I have more than one movement speed, how do they interact with mounting a steed?

Tags: dnd-5e, movement, mounted-combat

The rules for mounted combat state:

> Once during your move, you can mount a creature that is within 5 feet
> of you or dismount. **Doing so costs an amount of movement equal to half
> your speed.** For example, if your speed is 30 feet, you must spend 15
> feet of movement to mount a horse. Therefore, you can’t mount it if
> you don’t have 15 feet of movement left or if your speed is 0.

And the rules for movement in combat state:

> However you’re moving, you deduct the distance of each part of your
> move from your speed until it is used up or until you are done moving.

The default assumption is that "speed" refers to walking speed. But, how does this play out if e.g. I have a walking speed AND Fly has been cast on me, granting 60 ft flying speed? Can I mount the steed, as I always have, at the cost of 15 ft of movement? Or, does it suddenly cost 30 because of the fly spell? And, does it make a difference whether I mount the steed from the ground or from the air?

Comment: I've closed this as a duplicate, while the target question asks about standing up from prone with multiple speeds, the problem is exactly the same: doing something that costs half your movement while having multiple different movement speeds.